# Error when creating a template and then parsing from files

Tags: go

I don't know if I made some mistake or hit a golang's bug. The following code does not work as I expect and returns:

- *error:  template: name: "name" is an incomplete or empty template; defined templates are: "test.tmpl"*

---

**test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    t1 := template.New("name")
    t2 := template.Must(t1.ParseFiles("test.tmpl"))
    err := t2.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error: ", err)
    }
}
```

---

**test.tmpl**

```
{{"\"test ok\""}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem. According the [package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.ParseFiles), the template should usually have the name of one of the names of the files.

**Corrected code**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    t1 := template.New("test.tmpl")
    t2 := template.Must(t1.ParseFiles("test.tmpl"))
    err := t2.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error: ", err)
    }
}
```